# The oracle also tells you that you will die unless you can answer

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a function g(x, y). The oracle at Delphi has told you that g(1, 1) = 12 and dg(1,1) = 4/3 dx − 1/3 dy. The oracle also tells you that you will die unless you can tell it what g(0.9, 1.2) is equal to. Can you survive?

I am thinking all I need to do is this:
dg(1-0.9,1-1.2)=dg(0.1,-0.2)=(4/3*0.1)-(1/3*-0.2)=1/5
so g(0.9,1.2)=12+1/5
is this right?

Comment: Tell the oracle you'll need eighty years to think about it, then you'll answer.

Comment: The oracle is right, because it's a given that you will die -- eventually -- no matter what you answer. Apparently the oracle did not claim any connection between what your answer is and _when_ you will die.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to read what you did without mathjax, in any case, the end result is not correct.

It depends on if the oracle wants an exact value but it appears the oracle wants a linear approximation, which is given by first order taylor's in two variables
$$
g(.9,1.2)=g(1,1)+\frac{4}{3}dx-13dy=12-\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{10}-13\frac{2}{10}\\
=12-\frac{2}{15}-\frac{39}{15}=11+\frac{217}{3}
$$

Comment: There was a mistake in the question. 13 is supposed to be 1/3.

Comment: @KelKel23 can you modify the linear approximation above for the correct value of g at (1,1)?

Comment: it's correct now, right?